# What do they mean in ADC datasheet?

Tags: voltage, adc

I have an analog signal in the range of -12v to +12v and I want to read it by a high resolution ADC. In other words, I do not want to use a resistance divider or other scaling methods such as op-amp circuits. I searched on google a lot and found the [AD7732](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7732.pdf).

Now I have several related questions to the part:

1. Does anyone know other alternative ADC to choose? I need high resolution and ±12v range and speed is not important for me.
2. Does the AD7732 provide a direct reading of an analog input in the range of ±12V or only ±10V?
3. What do these sentences mean in the datasheet?

   a. Overvoltage tolerant

   b. Up to ±16.5 V not affecting adjacent channel

   c. Up to ±50 V absolute maximum

   d. The AD7732 is a high precision, high throughput **analog front end**.

Comment: Do you have just one analog signal?

Comment: In one application I have one analog signal and in other one, I have two analog signals.

Comment: What is the lowest resolution accepted?

Comment: @Oka at worst, 16 bit resolution.

Comment: You may check http://www.ti.com/product/ADS8568 16-bit ADC with +/-12V input range

Comment: This is a very tough requirement (relatively high voltage for an ADC, especially a precision ADC). I don't think you will find any IC ADC that accepts high voltage but doesn't have resistive divider scaling implemented on-chip. Would you consider using a `system calibration procedure` to compensate the offset and gain errors of an input divider? As long as the input conditioning circuitry is linear and has sufficient dynamic range for your signal, this would be the most straightforward and flexible way to proceed.

Comment: @MarkU the reason which forces me to NOT think about scaling is errors and imprecise calculation. I will be happy if there is a way to compensate these erros. Can you please suggest me some circuits for `system calibration procedure`?

Comment: Why can't you use a potential divider - 99 times out of a hundred that's the right way to go. You can really high precision pot dividers with temp specs as low as 1ppm/degC and accuracies in the sub 0.01% range.

Comment: Calibrate the system offset (offset error) by measuring a 0V signal through the divider. Calibrate the system fullscale (gain error) by measuring a full-scale reference signal through the divider. When calculating voltage of code, use `linear interpolation` between the measured "system offset" code and measured "system fullscale" code. Test for non-linearity by measuring at 25%, 50%, and 75% of full-scale.

Comment: The alternative to using a potential divider (if you really require direct "high voltage" ADC) would be building your own ADC from discrete components, using either a `delta-sigma` modulator or a `dual-slope converter` architecture like a DVM uses. In this scenario you are responsible for all accuracy and precision issues. Dual-slope requires a sampling capacitor with very low dissipation factor, traditionally paper or polypropelyne... not sure if those are still manufactured. I think you're probably better off using a standard IC ADC and calibrating-out the input divider's linear error.

Comment: @MarkU your first solution is fine. In my searching I found segregation of analog and digital power supplies can increase precision. How much does it affect? Do you know some useful link providing tips to segregate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The AD7732 is a high precision, high throughput analog front end.

An analog front-end is basically a term relating to modern digital systems.  Modern digital systems typically use low voltages, anywhere from 5V and below.  Well analog voltages are typically higher than that, but they still need to be interfaced with digital systems.  The solution is a separate integrated circuit that will handle the measurement of analog voltages and signals and then interface with the lower voltage digital system to relay that information.

> Overvoltage tolerant
>
> Up to ±50 V absolute maximum

What they mean by overvoltage tolerant is basically if your signal somehow jumps up to a higher voltage, the ADC shouldn't be damaged past the point of no return, but that doesn't mean it can't still get damaged.  Its just that they are willing to sign off that the device should still respond to commands and requests should any voltage up to ±50V occur.

> Up to ±16.5 V not affecting adjacent channel

If your input signal goes up/down to ±16.5V, it won't affect the readings that take place on the adjacent channel.  If it goes beyond that though, your readings on the other channels will start to be less accurate.

> Does AD7732 provide for me directly reading analog input in the range of ±12 or only ±10?

The device is only marked as reading between ±10V but that doesn't mean that it can't do better than that.  This value is just what the company feels comfortable marketing as.  Although the value isn't to be taken lightly.  If the fabricator says the chip can only handle ±10v, only use it in that situation or bad things can happen.

After doing some digging, turns out, looking at page 27, you will achieve up to ±11.6V readings without more rapidly degrading your ADCs performance.  Once you go over the ±10V range, the OVR bit in the channel status register will be set and your data value will be clipped to the lower 16 bits.  Take a look at Table 16 and 17 on that page and it should be pretty clear.

With all of that said, I wouldn't recommend using this IC for your application.  Even though the chip won't explode at much larger voltages, it simply wasn't designed to accurately measure up those voltages.

Comment: Dear Funkyguy, Do you know other alternative ADC to choose?

Comment: @NTS I can't recommend one in particular, I'm not intimate with your application.  Although Maxim and TI might be a good place to start. Also feel free to upvote or accept the answer

Comment: Is there a high resolution (24bit) ADC which reads above ±10V? In my searching I found as the higher bit resolution, the thiner voltage range. Is it correct? Meanwhile I can't vote up because of my low reputation.